# How to return a dart list without creating another list inside the function?

Tags: list, function, dart

```
List<int> getNumbers() {
  List<int> numbers = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
  }
  return numbers;
}
```

I want to return a List of integers but the list itself is generated using a loop, so is there is any way to directly return the values of the loop without creating another list to store the values of each iteration?

Comment: If you want to return multiple values, you need to store them *somehow*.  To return them all at once, you'd therefore need to store them in a collection of some kind (usually a `List`).  If you'd rather lazily return one value at a time and let the caller request the next value, you can use a [generator function](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generators).

Comment: If the use case is literally what you wrote, you could use `return list.generate(100, (index) => index);` and save yourself the for-loop, but you can't save yourself the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are asking for.
You want to return a list, but you also don't want to *create* a list.

You are not creating *another* list inside the function. You are creating *the* list, and then returning that list. There is only one list in play.

But, you can write it differently too.

First of all, your functions should probably be a getter named `numbers`, [not a function named `getNumbers`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-starting-a-method-name-with-get).

You can also create the list in a single expressions:

```dart
 [for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) i]
```

What you can do differently is *return an iterable*:

```dart
Iterable<int> get numbers sync* {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
}
```

That won't create a *list* at all.

Or, if you don't want to create a *new* list each time, cache it:

```dart
List<int>? _numbers;
List<int> get numbers() => _numbers ??= [
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) i
];
```

or just

```dart
final List<int> numbers = [
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) i
];
```

That will create only one list, and reuse it every time you ask for it (which can be a problem because the list is mutable, so only do this if you trust the reader to not modify the list!)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a getter that returns the list of numbers directly using the List generate function, for example

```
List<int> get getNumbers => List.generate(100, (index) => index + 1);
```

Or use a method

```
List<int> getNumbers() {
  return List.generate(100, (index) => index + 1);
}
```